# Required middlewares for RailsAdmin are not added (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error while trying to run the Rails server.

> Required middlewares for RailsAdmin are not added (RuntimeError) To
>   fix this, add
>
> config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore,
>   {:key=>"_nurseio-backend_session"}
>
> to config/application.rb.

I have added the line to config/application.rb still getting the error. Its happening from past few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention what version of `rails_admin` you are using, but if it is `1.4.x`, [there is a bug](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/3076#issuecomment-583985190).

It is fixed on the tip of the `1.x-stable` branch, but there has not yet been a release.

You can use GitHub and the branch as a source for the gem in your Gemfile:

`gem 'rails_admin', github: 'sferik/rails_admin', branch: '1.x-stable'`

Or, you can wait for a release.